# Should I add sequelize-typescript to my project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I know sequelize v6 provides built in support for typescript as the [documentation states](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/typescript/) But I also see the [sequelize-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-typescript) npm module is still active and it does require sequelize v6 so I wonder:

- in which uses cases should I use it?
- what are the benefits?
- why is it still needed?
- does it introduce performance penalties?

I really can't understand but the only thing that comes to my mind is, if I use plain sequelize, I will need to do `Model.init` and define all the attributes there. Otherwise, if I go for sequelize-typescript I will avoid doing that

- Am I correct?
- Is that the only (not only but you know) benefit?

Comment: If it helps, the contributing instructions for sequelize-typescript say "`sequelize-typescript` does not provide typings for `sequelize` - these are seperate things. A lot of the types in `sequelize-typescript` augment, refer to, or extends what `sequelize` already has."